# Get Android Bitmap Byte Count i (API level 18 - 28)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I Wouldn't find out how to calculate `bitmap` `byteSize` for managing memory.

I searched a lot but can't find the right and robust way to do this.

I also heared about `getByteCount()` and `getAllocationByteCount()`(it persent on 19 and above) but isn't help me. If it Help me so How?

is Their Robust way to get byte size of `Bitmap`.

My `API Level` is `18 - 28`

Thanks. (this similar question asked 8 years ago but it doesn't help me)

Comment: `Int sizeInBite = Bitmap.width * Bitmap.Height * getBytePerPixel(Bitmap.getConfig());`  **this is right way?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN KOTLIN

```
/**
 * it return size of Bitmap in Bytes.
 */
fun Bitmap.size(): Int{
    val s = rowBytes * height
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        return try {
            allocationByteCount
        } catch (npe: NullPointerException) {
            s
        }
    }
    return s
}
```